# Perl Regular Expression Needed

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking for a Perl Regex to extract all images from the following code:

```
slideshowimages("images/image1.jpg","images/image2.png","images/image3.jpg")
slideshowimages('images/image4.jpg','images/image5.png','images/image6.jpg')
```

The output would be an array with:

```
images/image1.jpg, images/image2.png, images/image3.jpg, images/image4.jpg, 
images/image5.png, images/image6.jpg
```

The things to pay attention to are:

- Image extension could be .jpg / .png
- Image could be inside singe or double quotes

What i've tried so far:

```
while ($html =~ /["|'|=](.*\.jpg|gif|png|bmp|swf).*"/g) {
    my $item = $1;
    $item =~ s/\"|\'|=//g;
    push (@images, $item);
}
```

But this doesn't really work well.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @images = $html =~ /["'] (.+?) ["']/gx; # /g for multiple hits on a line
```

Comment: @Bulletmagnet tnx for edit, but `/m` is useful only for anchoring (`^$`)

Answer (score 2):

A simple regex could be:

```
["'][^'"]*[.](jpg|png)["']
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

It would fail though on paths including `'` or `"` like `slideshowimages("images/image'1'.jpg")`. The expression than can handle this case would be:

```
('.*?\.(jpg|png)')|(".*?\.(jpg|png)")
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: how did you make that image?

Comment: Yes, debuggex. Great tool

Answer (score 1):

```
/(["']).*?\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp|swf)\1/
```

You need to capture what you're using, a single or a double quote, and refer back to that.
Also, you need to group your choices for the extension. Otherwise, you're saying 'anything ending with jpg OR just plain gif (, png, and so on)'.

---

Adjusting @mpapec's answer:

```
my @images = $html =~ /(["'])[^"']*?\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp|swf)\1/g;
```

(Disallowing " and ' within the filename is probably a good idea too).

Answer (score 1):

```
my $html = <<EOF;
slideshowimages("images/image'1'.jpg","images/image2.png","images/image3.jpg")
slideshowimages('images/image4.jpg','images/image5.png','images/image6jpg')
EOF

my @images = ();
while ($html =~ s/(["'])(.+?\/.+?\.(?:jpg|png|gif))\1//) {
    push @images, $2;
}
foreach my $image (@images) {
        print "$image, ";
}
```

This is a bit more restrictive so it does not get "images/image6png"

Does not fail on "images/image'1'.jpg"

(["']) - either a single or double quote (any character between the brackets) and capture

( - begin capture

.+?/ - one or more characters up to first slash

.+?. - one or more characters up to first period

(?: - begin grouping without capture

jpg|png|gif - any of the strings

) - end grouping without capture

) - end capture

\1 - captured single or double quote

Comment: My first thought was that images/image'1'.jpg is an impossible file name, but it is not on *nix - vi "image'1'.jpg"  (though it is ridiculous, imho)